# Ступеньки: подъем и спуск с указанием последовательности изменения координат объекта

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, уважаемые программисты! Помогите, пожалуйста, написать программу в `javascript`. У неё следующая формулировка: Количество ступенек величина случайная. Высота каждой ступеньки равна выбранной единице, а ширина может меняться случайным образом от 1 до 3. Необходимо воспроизвести подъем и спуск по ступенькам, указав последовательность изменения координат движущегося объекта, который может делать шаги равные выбранной единице в горизонтальном и вертикальном направлениях. Подскажите, с чего начать!

Comment: @niko, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: насколько я понял, вам нужно что-то вроде этого? http://jsfiddle.net/K9X5s/

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/121008/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%86%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

Начните с построение алгоритма программы. Вы там блок-схемы ведь уже проходили?

Comment: Да проходили.Т.е.с начала начать с генератора случайных чисел?

Comment: Что-то условие немного запутанное. У вас программа должна сама определить последовательность, по которой возможен подъем и спуск или просто проверить заданную последовательность?

Comment: Скорее всего нужно самому составить последовательность и программа проверив её, начнет выполнять.Как только составить последовательность?

Comment: Вам нужен массив объектов вида

    [{
     w : ...,
     h : ...
    }, {
     w : ...,
     h : ...
    },
     {...}];